# Demonstrate that graphs with different colors of vertices/edges are not isomorphic

Tags: graphs-and-networks, igraphm

I am asking explicitly about the IGraphM package. I do the following:

```
<< IGraphM`
Clear[vrts, edgs, gr]
connections = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {3, 6}};
vrts[1] = <|1 -> 1|>;
vrts[2] = <|2 -> 2|>;
edgs[1] = <|1 <-> 2 -> 1|>;
edgs[2] = <|3 <-> 6 -> 1|>;
g = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ connections];
gr[1] = {g, "VertexColors" -> vrts[1], "EdgeColors" -> edgs[1]};
gr[2] = {g, "VertexColors" -> vrts[2], "EdgeColors" -> edgs[1]};
gr[3] = {g, "VertexColors" -> vrts[1], "EdgeColors" -> edgs[2]};
IGVF2IsomorphicQ[gr[1], gr[1]]
IGVF2IsomorphicQ[gr[1], gr[2]]
IGVF2IsomorphicQ[gr[1], gr[3]]
```

There results are, of course, as expected. But now I would like to plot three graphs in order to show that they are indeed not isomorphic because of different colors of vertices/edges. I am suspecting that there is maybe a function from the same package that does exactly that. But I could not find. What is the idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps just do something using `HighlightGraph`?

Comment: @jjc385 Yes, that is one possibility. However, can it handle more that two colors? I actually know how to color a graph, but was hoping that there is already a function that can take advantage of "VertexColors" and "EdgeColors".

Comment: I'll look into making this task easier for the next version.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you currently using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the question was simple, so is the answer

```
decorateGraph[gr_, vrts_, edgs_] := Module[{gv},
  gv = Fold[
    SetProperty[{#1, #2}, {VertexStyle -> 
        ColorData[60, vrts[[Key[#2]]] ], VertexSize -> Medium}] &, g, 
    Keys[vrts]];
  Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, 
     EdgeStyle -> {ColorData[60, edgs[[Key[#2]]]], Thick}] &, gv, 
   Keys[edgs]]
  ]
```

and apply

```
decorateGraph[g, vrts[2], edgs[2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is just fine.  I just wanted to show a slightly different implementation which I find easier to work with.

```
decorateGraph[g_?GraphQ, vc_?AssociationQ, ec_?AssociationQ] :=
 Graph[g,
  VertexStyle -> Normal[ColorData[60] /@ vc],
  EdgeStyle ->   Normal[{Thick, ColorData[60][#]} & /@ ec],
  VertexSize ->  Thread[Keys[vc] -> Medium],

  GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack" (* this is just to make the rest of the graph render in black *)
 ]
```

The key thing to notice is that when colours are given in the association form, they are just a few steps away from the form required in `Graph`-options: rule lists.

```
decorateGraph[g, vrts[2], edgs[2]]
```

[image]

---

Something to keep in mind is that Mathematica 11.2 changed the interpretation of `<->` from `UndirectedEdge` to `TwoWayRule`.  `TwoWayRule` *should* work everywhere where `UndirectedEdge` does, but due to some bugs it doesn't. Thus to make this work with your example, change `<->` to `UndirectedEdge` (type it as ESC ue ESC)

IGraph/M will handle `TwoWayRule` in edge colour specifications starting with the next version (to be released before the end of 2017).

---

The next version of IGraph/M will make it easy to take vertex or edge colours from any existing [graph attributes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphProperties.html).  If you do that, then `IGVertexMap` and `IGEdgeMap` will make it easy to visualize the graph.  Unfortunately, working with graph attributes is still so cumbersome that it is not really worth the trouble in my opinion.